# Leaving a country without entering another country and coming back

Tags: air-travel, dxb, doha

I am planning to go to Dubai from Doha just to accompany my wife who is coming from Egypt. I will not be leaving Dubai's airport and will basically be coming back with her on the same flight. I wonder if it's possible? Is it advised?

Just to clarify, I am a resident of Qatar and she has a valid visa to enter Qatar.

Comment: What nationality are you?  Do you need a visa to enter the UAE?

Comment: Alright guys, I do need a visa to enter the UAE. But I can get one on arrival. I am not a Qatari citizen, but resident. My question was not whether I needed a visa or not, it was more about whether I could avoid the hassle of going through the not-needed immigration hassle.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not you intend to leave the airport, you will likely be required to go through immigration in Dubai. According to http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx, citizens of some countries require a visa in order to enter the UAE (Qatar is part of the GCC so citizens of Qatar do not need a visa). However, this may not apply if the layout of the airport is such that you can board your return flight without leaving the international transit lounge. I have not been to the Dubai airport so I am not certain whether this is the case. I would contact your airline to see what their policy says about your trip.

**EDIT**: According to the map at http://www.dubaiairports.ae/docs/default-source/map/dxb-terminal-2-map.pdf, the only way you could possibly avoid going through passport control is through [flydubai transfers](http://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/connections/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Not sure what to do. Called the airlines office and the guy barely spoke English. After talking with him for more than 10 minutes, he told me that he didn't know. Here's a link to the map of terminal 2(which is used for both inbound and outbound flights). http://www.dubaiairports.ae/docs/default-source/map/dxb-terminal-2-map.pdf?sfvrsn=6

Comment: Would really appreciate your help if you could draw some sort of conclusion from the map.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the map, I hadn't found that. It looks like the only way you could possibly avoid going through passport control is through [flydubai transfers](http://www.flydubai.com/en/plan/connections/). In this case you would not need a UAE visa.

Comment: Citizens of Qatar do not require visas for the UAE, since they're both in the GCC.  However, the nationality of the OP is not clear.

Comment: @jpatokal: Thanks, I was wondering about something like that. Can you find a page that describes this exception for GCC citizens?

Comment: The Emirates page you linked to says: "Citizens of the GCC nations of Bahrain, Kuwait, Oman, Qatar and Saudi Arabia do not require a visa to travel to the UAE."

Comment: Doh... clearly I missed that. Thanks <:) But your point about the citizenship of the OP remains valid.

Comment: Alright guys, I do need a visa to enter the UAE. But I can get one on arrival. I am not a Qatari citizen, but resident. My question was not whether I needed a visa or not, it was more about whether I could avoid the hassle of going through the not-needed immigration hassle.

Comment: @GregHewgill Thank you for the answer. So if I use FlyDubai transfers, do you think I can get my boarding pass at the counter in the gate? How should I go about receiving my return boarding pass?

Comment: @Mohammad well you either are flying with FlyDubai, or you aren't. If your airline is not FlyDubai then you may not be able to use their no-visa shortcut. Like your citizenship, we don't know if you don't tell us.

Comment: @GregHewgill: I am flying with FlyDubai and the flight goes to terminal 2. The return flight is from the same terminal.

Comment: @Mohammad: Well it sounds like you'll be fine. You should be able to use the FlyDubai shortcut and avoid going through immigration. Of course, you'll have to meet your wife after she passes through the exit passport control. Just make sure you pick up boarding passes for both your outgoing and return flight when you check in.

Comment: @GregHewgill: Thanks. She is also having a connecting flight. Does she still have to go through the exit passport control?

Comment: @Mohammad: I guess that depends on whether she is also flying with FlyDubai and can use the FlyDubai shortcut. Since she is coming from Egypt, that is probably true and therefore she would also not need to go through passport control in Dubai.